# How can I add values from pandas group to new Dataframe after a function?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to separate a Dataframe into groups, run each group through a function, and have the return value from the first row of each group placed into a new Dataframe.

When I try the code below, I can print out the information I want, but when I try to add it to the new Dataframe, it only shows the values for the last group.

How can I add the values from each group into the new Dataframe?

Thanks,

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Build random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,40,size=10),
                  columns=["Random"],
                  index=pd.date_range("20200101", freq='6h',periods=10))
df["Random2"] = np.random.randint(70,100,size=10)
df["Random3"] = 2


df.index =df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
df.index.name = 'Date'
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Setup groups by date 
df = df.groupby(['Date']).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index())
df.drop(["index","Date"],axis=1,inplace = True)

#Creat new dataframe for newValue
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=(df.index)).unstack()

#random function for an example
def any_func(df):
    df["Value"] = df["Random"] * df["Random2"] / df["Random3"]

    return df["Value"]

#loop by unique group name
for date in df.index.get_level_values('Date').unique():
    #I can print the data I want
    print(any_func(df.loc[date])[0])
    #But when I add it to a new dataframe, it only shows the value from the last group
    df2["newValue"] = any_func(df.loc[date])[0]
df2
```

Comment: You assign `df2["newValue"]`, which is the **entire** column, every loop. Yes, you have pre-specified the index so the values will only align on index, but because you're setting the **entire** column rows which were non-null on prior iterations get overwritten until the very last. If you want updating logic you'd use something like `combine_first`, or probably a bit easier append the results to a list and then call `pd.concat(that_list)` after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what's happening. Could you provide some code on how to solve the issue with updating logic?

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated, but try modifying your `any_func` to take advantage of vectorized functions is possible.

Now if I understand you correctly:

```
new_value = df['Random'] * df['Random2'] / df['Random3']
df2['New Value'] = new_value.loc[:, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works perfect if I pull the code out of the function, but when I try to run it inside the function it returns the error: "IndexingError: Too many indexers".

Answer (score 0):

This line of code gave me the desired outcome. I just needed to set the index using the "date" variable when I created the column, not when I created the Dataframe.

```
df2.loc[date, "newValue"] = any_func(df.loc[date])[0]
```